# How to make a box with grey color background using fbox in latex

Tags: color, backgrounds, fbox

how to make a box with grey color background using fbox in latex?

I have the following code but have no idea how to change the background into grey color.

```
\fbox{$\phantom{\num{665}}$}
```

Appreciate for any help

Comment: `\colorbox{grey}{$\phantom{\num{665}}$}`  should do the trick.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, I entered my answer before read your comment...

Comment: Hi Bernard, for some reason your suggestion not working, I dont know where I do wrong

Comment: Maybe something conflicting in the rest of your code? Is `\num` defined?

Comment: I got the following error: Undefined contol sequence

Comment: @Bernard May be the error due to the typo error, you mentioned color as `grey`, hope it should be as `gray`

Comment: @MadyYuvi: It was not a typo, but as the O.P. wrote it the same way, I forgot to mention it requires `xcolor` with option `svgnames`.

Comment: @Bernard Understood, please excuse ...

Comment: @MadyYuvi No problem. I should reread what I wrote more carefully  before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with `\colorbox{gray!50}{\hbox to 5pc{\vbox to 5pc{}}}`

**Edit**

Please try with `\fcolorbox{black}{gray!50}{\hbox to 5pc{\vbox to 5pc{}}}`

Comment: Thanks, it work

Comment: Btw Yuvi, is it possible to change the border color from your proposed solution?

Comment: `Border color` means you need to get the `outer rule color` ? Please confirm if my understanding is correct...

Comment: The outer line that make the rectangle border

Comment: @polosepian Please refer the edited answer...

Comment: Thanks and really appreciate it

Comment: I hope it not to much, but may I know how to adjust the width of the border line? Also, from where I can get the documentation about, any good link you can suggest?

Comment: Its my pleasure to help... Please read the link https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#colorbox_and_fcolorbox about more possible boxes in `LaTeX`